# I m in state of validation where i want to allow user to add alphabate or combination of alphanumeric value but only number isnot allowed

Tags: laravel

I try to use functionality which laravel provides for validation but i didn't got desired output

i tried to use alphanumeric function but it allowing entire number value too

```
$request->validate([
            'model' => 'required|alpha_num|alpha',
        ]);
```

Restrict user to to insert only numeric number

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` for alphanumeric and `not_regex` for numbers:

```
$request->validate([
    'model' => 'required|regex:/^[a-z0-9]+$/i|not_regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines, using a look ahead to ensure there's at least one character.

```
/^(?=[a-z0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]*$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and got result

regex:/[A-Za-z]+?[0-9]*/